# Create queries across projects in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I'm trying to create queries across several projects.  I've got 7 or 8 queries in total and a dozen or so projects so thought that having some sort of script may make it easier.

I've come up with this (basically copy and paste from somewhere else admittedly) but I have no idea where/how to run it, and whether I've even got everything. I'm assuming that I haven't because I don't have the PAT token but I'm really not sure.

I'm completely out of my comfort zone with this but if I get one right then I'm hoping the rest will be easy because I'm just amending the query. Could anyone offer a bit of help?  Should I be using Visual Studio Code or something else to run this? Do I just drop this code in or am I missing something key??

```html
POST https://dev.azure.com/MattR778/ProjectA/_apis/wit/queries/{query}?api-version=5.0 

{ "name": "No Status Change", "wiql": "Select [System.Id], [System.WorkItemType], [System.Title], [System.AssignedTo], [System.State], [System.AreaPath], [System.IterationPath]
From WorkItems Where [System.TeamProject] = @project AND [System.WorkItemType] = 'User Story' AND [System.State] = 'New' AND [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StateChangeDate]
  < @startofday( '-90d') }
```

---

I thought I had it, and I got an error message because I hadn't put a " towards the end (rookie mistake). I've re-run it but I still can't get it to work. I feel like it's really close but I tried running the sample request on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/queries/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0 and it had a similar response so I don't think it's the body.

I'm getting back this message:

```html
{

"$id": "1",

"innerException": null,

"message": "TF401243: The query {query} does not exist, or you do not have permission to read it.",

"typeName": "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server.QueryItems.QueryItemNotFoundException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server",

"typeKey": "QueryItemNotFoundException",

"errorCode": 600288,

"eventId": 3200

}
```

I've added the PAT to the authorization tab, so not sure what the issue is. I think it's nearly there, and I've been able to link into my DevOps project before with a simple GET test (so I don't think it's an issue with the connection between Postman and DevOps?), but I'm a little unsure of where to go next with this.

[The full screenshot of what I've tried to run in Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QSHa.jpg)

Comment: Is there a reason you want to try to use the API vs. just using the built-in queries?

Comment: I've got 7 or 8 queries and a dozen or so projects, so thought it may be quicker to create them that way, rather than go through each project.  Some of the queries have lots of criteria (the example I chose was fairly simple) so was hoping I could do something else, other than build them up each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run REST API in PowerShell.

Here is the script.

```
$token = "{PAT}"
$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
$url="https://dev.azure.com/MattR778/ProjectA/_apis/wit/queries/{query}?api-version=5.0"
$body = @'
{
    "name": "No Status Change",
    "wiql": "Select [System.Id], [System.WorkItemType], [System.Title], [System.AssignedTo], [System.State], [System.AreaPath], [System.IterationPath] From WorkItems Where [System.TeamProject] = @project AND [System.WorkItemType] = 'User Story' AND [System.State] = 'New' AND [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StateChangeDate]< @startofday( '-90d')
}
'@
$head = @{ Authorization =" Basic $token" }
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Post -Headers $head -Body $body -ContentType application/json
```

You can run the script in PowerShell or the PowerShell task in Azure DevOps pipeline.

In addition, you can also use some softwares designed to run APIs, like Postman.

**Update:**

In Postman, if you want to authenticate with PAT, you need to select "Basic Auth" in "Authorization" and enter PAT in the "Password".

[image]

In "Body", you need to select "raw" and choose "JSON". Then, paste your request body in the testbox.

[image]

The scripts above are for command-line tools such as PowerShell or Bash. If you are using Postman, you'd just need to provide the request body.

**Update 2:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks - I tried to run this and although it didn't error - part of the results said that I needed to disable the Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration (or something like that) and the query wasn't created.  I don't know if it's just because of what I was using (Visual Studio code) but perhaps it will work with something else?

Comment: @MattR Could you provide detailed message of that part of results? You can use postman and it would provide specific error messages when the REST API failed. If you have any questions, please come to me, I will be here to help you.

Comment: Thanks @Jane.  Postman seemed much more user friendly so that's been helpful.  It's now showing in Postman when I try to run it. I copied the code you kindly provided and added in the PAT.  Is there something else I should be swapping out??

{

    "count": 1,

    "value": {

        "Message": "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: $. Path '', line 0, position 0.\r\n"

    }

}

Comment: @MattR I have updated my answer. Please check whether it can help you.

Comment: Thanks Jane, appreciate all your help and just as importantly your patience.I've tried again and it's come up with a different error. I've updated my original post to show the message. Feels like it's so close to working now as well.

Comment: @MattR Sorry for the late response. In your request url `https://dev.azure.com/MattR778/ProjectA/_apis/wit/queries/{query}?api-version=5.0`, you need to replace `{query}` with a specific queries folder, such as `My%20Queries` and `Shared%20Queries`.